# merge sort recursion tree height

Tags: recursion, computer-science, tree

I am learning about recursion tree's and trying to figure out how the height of the tree is log b of n where n = 2 and one has 10 elements as input size. I am working with Merge sort.

The number of times the split is done is the height of the tree as far as I understood, and the number of levels in the tree is height + 1.

But if you take (for merge sort) log2 of 10 you get 1, where if you draw the tree you get at least 2 times that the recursion occurs.

Where have I gone wrong? (I hope I am making sense here)

NOTE: I am doing a self study, this is not homework!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

log<sub>2</sub>(10) = 3.321928094887362...

In any case, the recursive call depth is [O(log(n))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o), which basically means "on the order of log(n)". The actual call depth for an O(log(n)) algorithm might be `k*log(n)+c`, or even `k*log(n)+α(n)/log(log(n))+c`.